# Error in post css loader with webpack 3

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, css-loader, postcss-loader

I am using css loader with post css loader in webpack 3 in an angular project. When I am building my application I am getting following errors for all my css files:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./src/XXX/XXX/xxx.css
Module build failed: TypeError: WeakMap: incorrect invocation!
at TypeError (native)
at module.exports (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/core-js/modules/_an-instance.js:3:11)
at /home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/core-js/modules/_collection.js:59:9
at new WeakMap (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.weak-map.js:17:12)
at e (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:36380)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:27033)
at e (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:129)
at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:40119)
at e (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:129)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:149384)
at e (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:129)
at /home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:486
at /home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:1:497
at makeLoaderFunction (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:36:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/@std/esm/index.js:40:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (/home/anil/projects/expertly/client/webapp/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
```

This is my webpack config for css loader:

```
  {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'to-string-loader',
        { loader: 'css-loader' },
        'postcss-loader' 
      ],
      exclude: [
        path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules"),
      ]
    }
```

**postcss.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
  'autoprefixer': { browsers: 'last 2 versions' },
  'cssnano': {
    safe: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    autoprefixer: false
  },
  'postcss-import': {
    addDependencyTo: webpack
  },
  'postcss-cssnext': {}
  }
}
```

Versions used are are:

"postcss-loader": "2.0.7"

"webpack": "3.6.0"

Comment: Read my answer, it has a link to my boilerplate. see it and compare it with your config. Undoubtedly It can Help you.

Answer (score 1):

### PostCSS and Webpack

Excuse me for my words but your configurations has critical problems, I'm `React` Developer, but `Webpack` configs is not depended on `Angular` or `React` or something else, But why you don't have `fallback` inside your `rules` ?

Why you don't use `ExtractTextPlugin` ? and why you use `CSS` extension file when you wanna play with `PostCSS`? and other things like separated `PostCSS` file? why?

I proffer to you see my [PostCSS configuration on Webpack](https://github.com/amerllica/postcss-config-on-webpack) and compare it with your configs, my boilerplate work awesome, it use react, never mind, the `Webpack` version is `3.x` and `PostCSS` version is `6.0.x` and `postcss-loader` version `2.0.x`. And specially I separate Development and Production version of `Webpack`. it is easy to understand and clear and clean. if you have other questions please ask, I'll glad to answer.